# How to retrieve the value of a ListView item in the same row as a LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a dynamically generated ListView which displays a set of groups, retrieved from a database. The ListView template looks like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvGroups" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblGroupName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupName") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="lnkGroupRemove" OnClientClick="Confirm()" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

As you can see, there is a value, which is pulled from a database, and then a linkbutton for removing that value. When the linkbutton is clicked, it displays a javascript confirmation message, and if you click Yes on that message, then that specific entry will be removed from the database.

Unfortunately I cannot simply remove the GroupName where the ID = row number, because you can both add and remove groups, so that will quickly become inconsistent.

All I truly need is a way to retrieve the GroupName from the same row as the linkbutton that was clicked, if I can figure out how to do that, then I can easily configure a database query to successfully remove the entry. If you have another solution, however, that is also great.

I'm sad to say that I have no example code for the `lnkGroupRemove` event, as I simply have no clue where to start on this problem.

Any help on this subject would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your click event. You can reference to the tr using sender.parent then you can do findcontrol to get the lblgroupname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DataKeyNames` attribute:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvGroups" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID,GroupName" >
```

and get the value this way in code-behind:

```
protected void lnkGroupRemove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem item = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as ListViewItem;
    int ID = (int)lvGroups.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Values["ID"];
    string groupName = (string)lvGroups.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Values["GroupName"];
}
```

I added an ID value to show that additional fields can be added to `DataKeyNames` and retrieved from code-behind, including fields that are in the data source but not displayed in the ListView.

Comment: Honestly I've learned so much from this project in the past few days and I have to say the vast majority of it has to do with things you've answered. I didn't previously know about DataKeyNames but now I'm definitely going to go back and see what I can do with this functionality. It works great, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I wasn't aware that we had communicated before, due to your username which is not easy to distinguish from a few other similar ones. I will try to remember the user ending in "169". :-)