# Pass Text From a List View Controller to a OnClick Sub VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to pass text from a List View controller to a OnClick Subroutine? For example, there's a label in the List View and I've attached a Button in the List View and attached an OnClick Subroutine to it. Now I want to pass the text from the Label over to the OnClick Subroutine. I hope this make sense. Down below is my code:

VB.Net Code:

```
Protected Sub AmButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  Dim url As String = CType(Me.AmListViewDetails.FindControl("merchantLink"), Label).Text
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
  sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>"_
  sb.Append("window.open('")
  sb.Append(url)
  sb.Append("');")
  sb.Append("</script>")
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

ASP.Net:

```
<asp:ListView runtat="server" ID="AmListViewDetails"  ...>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <table runat="server">
       <tr runat="server">
          <td runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="merchantLink" runat="server" Text='<%Eval("Link")%>' />
          </td>
       </tr>

       <tr runat="server">
         <td runat="server">
           <asp:Button ID="AmBtn" runat="server" Text="Checkout" OnClick="AmButtonClick"/>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: The best way to retrieve the value of the `Link` field is to add that field to the `DataKeyNames` property of the ListView. The method is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813634/how-to-retrieve-the-value-of-a-listview-item-in-the-same-row-as-a-linkbutton/36814031#36814031.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `CommandArgument` property to the button. That's going to be the value passed to the event handler. You don't need an `OnClick` property.

```
<asp:Button ID="AmBtn" runat="server" Text="Checkout" CommandArgument="???" />
```

Your event handler would be

```
Sub AmListViewDetails_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e) 
    Dim valuePassedFromListView = Cstr(e.CommandArgument)
End Sub
```