# (ASP.NET) Get the bound object using a button column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm writing a project for libraries and I have a table of borrowed books. On the website, each customer can log in and ask to extend the period. I need a way to get the object (type Borrowed) which is in the row of the button.
This is what I have:

```
         <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="button" OnClick="MyButtonClick" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
    Customer cus = (Customer)Session["Customer"];
    List<Borrowed> bl = client.BorrByCusId(cus.Id);
    BooksGrid.DataSource = bl;
    BooksGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You can use the procedure described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813634/how-to-retrieve-the-value-of-a-listview-item-in-the-same-row-as-a-linkbutton/36814031#36814031. (1) Add the `Id` field to `DataKeyNames`, (2) In the button event handler, use the `NamingContainer` of the button to get the GridViewRow, (3) Retrieve the Id with the `DataKeys` value, (4) Get the Borrowed object with the Id. If the procedure is not clear, I can adapt the answer to fit your needs (except for step 4, which depends on your specific code).

Comment: In your question, you just ask to get the "row". The GridViewRow is given by the `NamingContainer` property of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrap the logic that binds your `GridView` in the `Page_Load` event in `if(!Page.IsPostBack){}`
2. Handle the `OnRowCommand` event of the `GridView`
3. Change your button inside the GridView to be a command button and pass through the `GridView` row index as a parameter.

Below is the complete example.

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBooks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvBooks_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Extend" CommandName="ExtendPeriod" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class GridViewGetBoundObject : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Book> books = this.GetBooks();
            gvBooks.DataSource = books;
            gvBooks.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        var book1 = new Book { ID = 0, Title = "Wuthering Heights" };
        var book2 = new Book { ID = 1, Title = "The Alchemist" };
        var book3 = new Book { ID = 2, Title = "Little Prince" };

        return new List<Book> { book1, book2, book3 };
    }

    protected void gvBooks_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName == "ExtendPeriod")
        {
            GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[index];

            string bookId = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string bookName = row.Cells[1].Text;
        }
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Output when "Extend button is clicked":**

[image: Handling the OnRowCommand event of the GridView in ASP.NET]